# How to resolve Cannot find parent for maven affuse project in spring tool suite ubuntu

Tags: hibernate, maven

when I try to execute maven command to generate service and dao's for my hibernate model classes i,e

mvn appfuse:gen -Dentity="ModelClassName" I am getting

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent for project: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 for project commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
```

I could n't able to resolve this problem. where it is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Change the version from 1.1.1 to 1.1.3

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```